# GL_ERROR == 1282 for both glVertexAttribPointer and glDrawArrays only when using a opengl 3.2 context or higher

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I am not 100% sure here where the error described in the title of this post stems from. It could be the context creation or it could be the actual drawing code. I will start with the drawing code. The code below will render with a 2.0 to a 3.1 versioned context but stops rendering at 3.2 context or higher. It should be noted that the context is created with the glX family of functions. If that code is needed please post in the comments section. I am also assuming that the error for glDrawArrays is connected to the error generated when getting the vertex attribute pointer for the "position" variable in the vertex shader?

The drawing and initialization code is as follows:

```
void start_func()
{
  // Create Window
  // Create Context
  // Start Message Pump
  // Clean Up
}

GLuint vbo;
GLuint shaderProgram;

bool compiler_errors(GLuint shaderId)
{
  bool errors = false;

  GLint isCompiled = 0;

  glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);
    GL_CALL("glGetShaderiv")
  if(isCompiled == GL_FALSE) {
    GLint maxLength = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
      GL_CALL("glGetShaderiv")
    std::vector<char> errorLog(maxLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);
      GL_CALL("glGetShaderInfoLog")
    std::stringstream out;
    std::copy(errorLog.begin(), errorLog.end(),
      std::ostream_iterator<char>(out, ""));
    std::string errorsStr = out.str();
    std::cerr << "Shader Compiler Erros " << errorsStr.c_str();
    errors = true;
  }

  return errors;
}

void init()
{
  const GLchar* vertexSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 position;"
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "  gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";
  const GLchar* fragmentSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "out vec4 outColor;"
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "  outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);"
    "}";

  glGenBuffers(1, &vbo); GL_CALL(glGenBuffers)

  GLfloat vertices[] = {
    +0.0f, +0.5f,
    +0.5f, -0.5f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f
  };

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo); GL_CALL(glBindBuffer)
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices,
    GL_STATIC_DRAW); GL_CALL(glBufferData)

  // Create and compile the vertex shader
  GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GL_CALL(glCreateShader)
  glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    GL_CALL(glShaderSource)
  glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    GL_CALL(glCompileShader)

  if(compiler_errors(vertexShader) == GL_TRUE) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to compile vertex shader.");
  }

  // Create and compile the fragment shader
  GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GL_CALL(glCreateShader)
  glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    GL_CALL(glShaderSource);
  glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    GL_CALL(glCompileShader);
  if(compiler_errors(fragmentShader) == GL_TRUE) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to compile fragment shader.");
  }

  // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
  shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    GL_CALL(glCreateProgram)
  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    GL_CALL(glAttachShader);
  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    GL_CALL(glAttachShader);
  glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    GL_CALL(glLinkProgram);
  glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    GL_CALL(glUseProgram);
}

void render()
{
  glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600); GL_CALL(glViewport)
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); GL_CALL(glClear)

  // Clear the screen to black
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GL_CALL("glClearColor")
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL_CALL("glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)")

  // Draw a triangle from the 3 vertices
  glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    GL_CALL("glUseProgram")
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    GL_CALL("glBindBuffer")

  GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    GL_CALL("glGetAttribLocation")
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    GL_CALL("glEnableVertexAttribArray")
  glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    GL_CALL("glVertexAttribPointer")
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    GL_CALL("glDrawArrays")
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    start_func();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, you set clear color once, and call glClear() in render but not muliple times. So move glClearColor out of loop and delete line glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

Comment: And what is GL_CALL? it makes your code super hard to read.

Comment: @eldo GL_CALL is a macro that checks for errors in opengl in a dbug build. In release it is an empty statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a Core Profile, using a vertex array object (VAO) is mandatory. Before 3.2, the VAO 0 was a valid object (so to say a global state VAO), but starting from 3.2 
Core, VAO 0 is an invalid object. Since you don't create and bind you own VAO, you get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error whenever you try to modify the VAO state (`glVertexAttribPointer`) or when you trying to draw using the invalid 0 VAO.

More Information can be found [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification).

Comment: Thanks BDL. I never would of guessed that was the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me to fix my problems. However, what you're saying is true from the 3.1 opengl's version. I tried with the 3.0 and it's working. with the 3.1 it's not.